# How to print folding marks with grails rendering service?

Tags: css, pdf, grails, rendering

A client wants to have folding marks and a repeating background image in a generated pdf. I tryed

```
<style  type="text/css">
 @page {
   size: 210mm 297mm;
 }
</style>
```

as stated in the [doc](http://gpc.github.io/grails-rendering/docs/manual/guide/single.html), but the there is always a white/blank frame around the content of the pdf. 
The client wants his background to stretch over the whole pdf and the folding marks inside this white/blank space. 
For me it looks like grails renderingservice reserves some space for a probably non printable area. How can I "print" to that area? 
I found nothing in the doc and google couldn't help either.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>...</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    @page {
      size: 210mm 297mm;
      margin: 0
    }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
   <div style="float:left">
     <div style="height:2px;width:6px;margin-top: 105mm; left:0;background-color: black"></div>
     <div style="height:2px;width:6px;margin-top: 105mm; left:0;background-color: black">   </div>
   </div>
   <div><!-- content here --></div>
   <div style="page-break-after:always;"></div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

But that leads to the next question: How to repeat the folding marks on every page in a generic way?